# How to connect connect firebase to react-native app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm new in react native, and I'm creating a simple test app. I followed the firebase documentation and inserted the dependencies and the google-services.json file. The problem is that now I would like to read the data from my realtime database, and following the documentation I did something like this:

```
...
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/app';

const Categories = () => {
const reference = firebase
.app()
.database('https://testapp-app-default-rtdb.euorpe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/')
.ref('/categories');
...
```

But if I running the command from the terminal: `npx expo start` to test the application on my Android phone, the console gives me this error:

```
ERROR  Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().
Ensure you have:
1) imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.
2) Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.
```

How can i solve this to test my app with db?

Comment: Did you follow the 2 steps which were given in the error?

Comment: Done, but i have the same error

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of **[React Native Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/#4-autolinking--rebuilding)** you are importing the the firebase module from **`@react-native-firebase/app`** instead of **`@react-native-firebase/database`**

> Once successfully linked and rebuilt, your application will be connected to Firebase using the @react-native-firebase/app module. This module does not provide much functionality, therefore to use other Firebase services, each of the modules for the individual Firebase services need installing separately.

So you have to install the Realtime-Database module to read data. Install the module using the command `npm install @react-native-firebase/database` rebuild the app.
Then simply import the database:

```
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';
const reference = database().ref('/categories');
```

If the database is not 'us-central1', that is your case, you can import it as below:

```
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/database';

const reference = firebase
  .app()
  .database('https://testapp-app-default-rtdb.euorpe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/')
  .ref('/categories');
```

Comment: I ran the command: npm install @react-native-firebase/database. Then I entered: import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/database'; but the problem was not solved

Comment: What versions of react-native-firebase you are using?

Comment: What I guess is you've Expo project, so, did you follow the expo documentation? https://rnfirebase.io/#expo also please install the @react-native-firebase/database using the expo cli npx expo install @react-native-firebase/database

Comment: I use: "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.5.0", "@react-native-firebase/database": "^17.5.0". I also installed firebase with command "expo cli npx expo install @react-native-firebase/database" but it doesn't work. Maybe the right command is "npx react-native run-android" but even in this case I have an error

Comment: could you please share your app.json file?

Comment: Yes i answer my question with app.json file

Comment: According to the documentation, you've to add the google-services.json file in the root of your project and run the command npx expo prebuild, that will change some native files.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't say it before. the google-services file is also located on the project root, I followed your steps but I get the same error